# Translate SVG matrix transform values into x,y coordinates

Tags: math, svg, matrix, graphics, transformation

I'm working on an SVG map, which contains a **lot** of `text` elements. The problem is, the old/source file has been generated years ago in Adobe Illustrator, which for some reason printed these elements as, e.g.:

`<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 604.9754 765.0283)">4</text>`

*(First four arguments (1, 0, 0, 1) never change.)*

What I want to achieve is to translate it into something like

`<text x='123' y='456'>4</text>`

I've already managed to collect all values needed using regex (text content and the two last transform arguments), but I have no idea what should I do next. I've also found out, that

> The **matrix(     )** transform function specifies a transformation in the form of a transformation matrix of six values. **matrix(a,b,c,d,e,f)** is equivalent to applying the transformation matrix:
>
> \begin{pmatrix} a & c & e \\ b & d & f \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
>
> which maps coordinates from a previous coordinate system into a new coordinate system by the following matrix equalities:
>
> \begin{pmatrix} x_{\mathrm{newCoordSys}} \\ y_{\mathrm{newCoordSys}} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a & c & e \\ b & d & f \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_{\mathrm{prevCoordSys}} \\ y_{\mathrm{prevCoordSys}} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a x_{\mathrm{prevCoordSys}} + c y_{\mathrm{prevCoordSys}} + e \\ b x_{\mathrm{prevCoordSys}} + d y_{\mathrm{prevCoordSys}} + f \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}

So my question is:

**how can I *translate* these matrix transform values into X,Y coordinates**?

Comment: If you have effects such as filters on the text you might not get the same results if you replace a transform with x, y

Comment: XSLT is the right tool for XML processing, not regex.

Answer (score 1):

I've found out, that `matrix(1 0 0 1 100px 200px)` is equivalent to `translateX(100px) translateY(200px)` which means, that these values **are actually the exact values** I've been looking for. The reason I didn't realize it earlier was because I didn't adjust them (multiply, add) to my new image. I've also used X as Y coordinates inversely (ouch). I hope it can help someone.